# With PyTorch, how is my Conv1d dimension reducing when I have padding?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

My `conv module` is:

```
        return torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Conv1d(
                in_channels=in_channels,
                out_channels=in_channels,
                kernel_size=2,
                stride=1,
                dilation=1,
                padding=1
            ),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.Conv1d(
                in_channels=in_channels,
                out_channels=in_channels,
                kernel_size=2,
                stride=1,
                dilation=2,
                padding=1
            ),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.Conv1d(
                in_channels=in_channels,
                out_channels=in_channels,
                kernel_size=2,
                stride=1,
                dilation=4,
                padding=1
            ),
            torch.nn.ReLU()
        )
```

And in `forward`, I have:

```
down_out = self.downscale_time_conv(inputs)
```

`inputs` has a `.size` of `torch.Size([8, 161, 24])`. I'd expect `down_out` to have the same size, but instead it has: `torch.Size([8, 161, 23])`

Where did that last element go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer can be found on Pytorch documentation online ([here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html)). For every operation the output shape is expressed with respect to the input parameters:

[image]

For each conv1D:

```
- L1 = 25 → int((24 + 2*1 - 1*(2 - 1) - 1) / 1 + 1)
- L2 = 25 → int((25 + 2*1 - 2*(2 - 1) - 1) / 1 + 1)
- L3 = 23 → int((25 + 2*1 - 4*(2 - 1) - 1) / 1 + 1)
```

Do not forget that `Lin` is the previous size.